# Subtract 7 days from current date

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

It seems that I can't subtract 7 days from the current date. This is how i am doing it:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:-7];
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

SevenDaysAgo gets the same value as the current date.

Please help.

EDIT: In my code I forgot to replace the variable which gets the current date with the right one. So above code is functional.

Comment: `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[NSDate date].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - (7*24*60*60)]` -- Though it doesn't handle DST changes.

Comment: That should work.  Does it work if you add 1 instead of subtract 7?  How do you determine that sevenDaysAgo refers to today?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

use dateByAddingTimeInterval method:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60];
NSLog(@"7 days ago: %@", sevenDaysAgo);
```

output:

```
7 days ago: 2012-04-11 11:35:38 +0000
```

Comment: There are edge cases where this won't work properly, for example if the daylight savings changes during the seven days in question.

Comment: dymv's answer is the safer way of doing this.

Comment: This is the wrong answer for the aforementioned reasons, use dymv's answer

Comment: Actually this can be done simply by: `[now dateByAddingDays:-7]`

Comment: Doing this kind of calculation is dangerours, prefer @Dov's version.

Answer (score 199):

**code:**

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:-7];
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSLog(@"\ncurrentDate: %@\nseven days ago: %@", currentDate, sevenDaysAgo);
[dateComponents release];
```

**output:**

```
currentDate: 2012-04-22 12:53:45 +0000
seven days ago: 2012-04-15 12:53:45 +0000
```

And I'm fully agree with JeremyP.

BR.
Eugene

Comment: There is a memory leak in this answer though.

Answer (score 144):

If you're running at least iOS 8 or OS X 10.9, there's an even cleaner way:

```
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                value:-7
                                                               toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                              options:0];
```

Or, with Swift 2:

```
let sevenDaysAgo = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -7,
    toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

And with Swift 3 and up it gets even more compact:

```
let sevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it handles all edge cases for you.

Comment: @ZhivkoBogdanov My answer came a few years after the accepted answer, and I don't believe you can change your accepted answer after the fact.

Comment: It's more for future reference than anything else.

Answer (score 68):

### Swift 3

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
```

Comment: Don't use NSCalendar, use Calendar instead :)

Answer (score 11):

### Swift operator extension:

```swift
extension Date {
    
    static func -(lhs: Date, rhs: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -rhs, to: lhs)!
    }
}
```

### Usage

```swift
let today = Date()
let sevenDayAgo = today - 7
```

Comment: Seems a good idea until you decide to subtract something thats not days

Answer (score 9):

## Swift 4.2 - Mutate (Update) Self

Here is another way the original poster can get one week ago if he already has a date variable (updates/mutates itself).

```
extension Date {
    mutating func changeDays(by days: Int) {
        self = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: self)!
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var myDate = Date()       // Jan 08, 2019
myDate.changeDays(by: 7)  // Jan 15, 2019
myDate.changeDays(by: 7)  // Jan 22, 2019
myDate.changeDays(by: -1) // Jan 21, 2019
```

#### or

```
// Iterate through one week
for i in 1...7 {
    myDate.changeDays(by: i)
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

dymv's answer work great. This you can use in swift

```
extension NSDate {    
    static func changeDaysBy(days : Int) -> NSDate {
        let currentDate = NSDate()
        let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = days
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    }
}
```

You can call this with

```
NSDate.changeDaysBy(-7) // Date week earlier
NSDate.changeDaysBy(14) // Date in next two weeks
```

Hope it helps and thx to dymv

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.2** iOS 11.x [Babec's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2798882/babac) solution, pure Swift

```
extension Date {
  static func changeDaysBy(days : Int) -> Date {
    let currentDate = Date()
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = days
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: currentDate)!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0+ version of the original accepted answer

Date().addingTimeInterval(-7 * 24 * 60 * 60)

However, this uses absolute values only. Use calendar answers is probably more suitable in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

Function to add or subtract day from current date.

```
func addOrSubtructDay(day:Int)->Date{
  return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: Date())!
}
```

Now calling the function

```
var dayAddedDate = addOrSubtructDay(7)
var daySubtractedDate = addOrSubtructDay(-7)
```

- To Add date pass prospective day value
- To Subtract pass negative day
  value

Comment: @EricAya thank your for your advice.

Answer (score -2):

Swift 3:

A modification to Dov's answer.

```
extension Date {

    func dateBeforeOrAfterFromToday(numberOfDays :Int?) -> Date {

        let resultDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: numberOfDays!, to: Date())!
        return resultDate
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let dateBefore =  Date().dateBeforeOrAfterFromToday(numberOfDays : -7)
let dateAfter = Date().dateBeforeOrAfterFromToday(numberOfDays : 7)
print ("dateBefore : \(dateBefore), dateAfter :\(dateAfter)")
```

Comment: Why is `numberOfDays` optional and then force-unwrapped? Shouldn't it just be a non-optional `Int`?

Comment: Its the proper way of containing optional value in swift function.

Comment: But why is numberOfDays optional? is there any time when someone will call this extension method and not give a number of days to add or remove?

Answer (score -3):

FOR SWIFT 3.0

here is fucntion , you can reduce days , month ,day by any count 
like for example here , i have reduced the current system date's year  by 100 year , you can do it for day , month also 
just set the counter 
and store it in an array , you can this array anywhere then 
func currentTime()

```
 {

    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let  day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let pastyear = year - 100
    var someInts = [Int]()
    printLog(msg: "\(day):\(month):\(year)" )

    for _ in pastyear...year        {
        year -= 1
                     print("\(year) ")
        someInts.append(year)
    }
          print(someInts)
        }
```